# Parceljs import javascript file as string

Tags: javascript, bundle, service-worker, parceljs

I have a very particular use case. I want to import a javascript file as a string and inject it into html responses at will in a service worker. I can't see how to do this using parceljs beyond hosting the javascript file somewhere and doing fetch at runtime to load the js file into memory. However, I want to do this at build time. How best to do this?

Note: Ideally the dependencies of javascript file I am importing should be bundled into the string.

Comment: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/970 This thread seems to indicate that you can make use of `fs.readFileSync` and it'll be processed at build time.

Comment: nice that's awesome! Ideally I need it to bundle the file I am importing too, so that won't quite work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be possible in parcel 2 with

```js
import js from "bundle-text:./b.ts";

console.log(js);
```

https://v2.parceljs.org/configuration/plugin-configuration/#predefined-(offical)-named-pipelines

Comment: https://parceljs.org/features/bundle-inlining/